# How do I add a point system to my Python Turtle Snake Game

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying to add points to my snake game where one point is added after drawing one line, but it keeps coming up with errors, e.g.,

this is my code:

```
# imports
import turtle
import time

# set up
screen=turtle.getscreen()
screen.title("Snake")
screen.bgcolor("light blue")
t=turtle.Turtle()

player_one_points = 0
player_two_points = 0

# start
snake1colour=input("What colour snake would player one like? (red, blue or yellow): ")
print("------------------------------")
snake2colour=input("What colour snake would player two like? (red, blue or yellow, but different to player one): ")

# choosing snake colour and setting them up
if snake1colour=='red':
    snake1=turtle.Turtle()
    snake1.shape("square")
    snake1.color("red")

elif snake1colour=='blue':
    snake1=turtle.Turtle()
    snake1.shape("square")
    snake1.color("blue")

elif snake1colour=='yellow':
    snake1=turtle.Turtle()
    snake1.shape("square")
    snake1.color("yellow")

if snake2colour=='red':
    snake2=turtle.Turtle()
    snake2.shape("square")
    snake2.color("red")

elif snake2colour=='blue':
    snake2=turtle.Turtle()
    snake2.shape("square")
    snake2.color("blue")

elif snake2colour=='yellow':
    snake2=turtle.Turtle()
    snake2.shape("square")
    snake2.color("yellow")

# choosing gridsize
gridsize=input("Would you like a gridsize of 3x3 (3), 5x5 (5), 10x10 (10) or 15x15 (15)?: ")


# gridsizes and colour input
if gridsize=='5':
    t.speed(50)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-200,200)

    snake1.penup()
    snake1.goto(-100,100)
    snake1.pendown()

    snake2.penup()
    snake2.goto(100,-100)
    snake2.pendown()

    def clear(x,y):
        snake1.clear()
        snake2.clear()
        snake1.penup()
        snake2.penup()
        snake1.goto(-100,100)
        snake2.goto(100,-100)
        snake1.pendown()
        snake2.pendown()
        player_one_points=0
        player_two_points=0


    screen.onclick(clear)

    # snake 1 definitions for directions
    def left():
        if snake1.xcor() >-200:
            snake1.setheading(180)
            snake1.fd(100)
            player_one_points +=1
            print("player one's points are ", player_one_points)
    
    def right():
        if snake1.xcor() <200:
            snake1.setheading(0)
            snake1.fd(100)
            player_one_points +=1
            print("player one's points are ", player_one_points)

    def up():
        if snake1.ycor() <200:
            snake1.setheading(90)
            snake1.forward(100)
            player_one_points +=1
            print("player one's points are ", player_one_points)


    def down():
        if snake1.ycor() >-200:
            snake1.setheading(270)
            snake1.fd(100)
            player_one_points +=1
            print("player one's points are ", player_one_points)

    # snake 2 definitions for directions
    def w():
        if snake2.ycor() <200:
            snake2.setheading(90)
            snake2.forward(100)
            player_two_points +=1
            print("player two's points are ", player_two_points)

    def a():
        if snake2.xcor() >-200:
            snake2.setheading(180)
            snake2.fd(100)
            player_two_points +=1
            print("player two's points are ", player_two_points)

    def s():
        if snake2.ycor() >-200:
            snake2.setheading(270)
            snake2.fd(100)
            player_two_points +=1
            print("player two's points are ", player_two_points)

    def d():
        if snake2.xcor() <200:
            snake2.setheading(0)
            snake2.fd(100)
            player_two_points +=1
            print("player two's points are ", player_two_points)
```

(there's more where i call the wasd and arrows i just left it out)

and it comes up with this when i move the snakes - the snakes move but the points don't work:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 685, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "/Users/chloeodonoghue/Documents/python snake game.py", line 99, in right
    player_one_points +=1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'player_one_points' where it is not associated with a value
```

also as a sidenote, could someone pls also help with alternating turns between players?

i tried a few diff things, such as changing the variables, changing the += 1 to + 1 or player_one_points = player_one_points + 1  and player_one_points1 = player_one_points + 1. None of them worked.

Comment: Add global `player_one_points` for every function from line 95  and some `player_two_points` too